# Excel: Return value A1 if D1 is between B1 and C1

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

probably basic but can't work it out for the life of me, after hours of playing with INDEX and SUMPRODUCT.

I have a spreadsheet of box numbers (column A), with two further columns containing the first (column B) and last (column C) file number contained in that box. eg box 10669 contains files 88880 to 88890.

Column D is a much longer list of individual file numbers and I want to put in column E, against each individual file number, the box number that it is contained in. eg file number 88885 is in box 10669 and so on.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Try this formula: =IF(AND(B1<D1,D1<C1),A1,"")

Answer (score 0):

You can do a straight `IF`:

```
=IF(AND(D1>MIN(B1,C1),D1<MAX(B1,C1)),A1,"")
```